# Loading large amount of data from local machine into Amazon Elastic Block Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am interested in doing some machine learning using an AWS EC2 instance. I have played around with launching instances with a an attached EBS and I was able to load files into it via `scp` on my local command line. I will have several gigabytes of data to load onto this EBS (I know that isn't a lot by ML standards but that's not really my point). I would like to know what is the appropriate way to load this data. I'm concerned about racking up large fees because I did something in a silly way.

So far I have just uploaded a few files to the EC2 instance's associated EBS manually via the command line, like this:

```
scp -i keys/ec2-ml-micro2.pem data/BB000000001.png ubuntu@<my instance ip>:/data
```

This seems to me to be a rather primitive approach (not that that is always a bad thing). Is it the "right" way? I'm not opposed to letting a batch jbb run overnight like this but I am not sure if it may incur some data transfer fees. I've looked around for information on this, and I have read the page on [EBS pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/). I didn't see anything on costs associated with loading data but I just wanted to confirm with someone or some people who have done something similar that this is the correct approach, and if not, what is a a better one

Answer (score 1):

In managing large objects in AWS. Always check for S3 as an initial option, it provides unlimited Storage capacity and best use for object store compared to EBS(block store). EBS billed you from the size of the volume that you provisioned, having said that there is a chance that you over-provisioned(overhead cost) or under-provisioned (can lead to poor performance or even downtime).

Using S3 you are billed for the storage that you consumed per GB per month, pay for what you use model and it's very cheap compared to EBS.

And lastly, try to evaluate first the AWS Machine Learning services that might fit for your use-cases it will save you alot of time and effort.

Data Transfer from S3 to EBS within the same region is free of charge.
[AWS Pricing Details](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws_pricing_overview.pdf)

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If I was training a machine learning model with tens of thousands of images, wouldn't EBS be better than S3 because it is mounted directly onto the file system? I thought that everything in S3 would have to be retrieved over the network and significantly slow down training.

Comment: True but you need to get the balance where your training model perform as expected and at the same time you don't get high bills. You can configure your training scripts to do by batch where in you take a certain bulk of object from S3, process, labeling and delete from EBS. It will make your training pipeline durable in case there is an outage.

Comment: I take it you have done this before using S3? By the way, I do know of the pre-built options offered by Amazon, but I am experimenting with an open source model directly.

Comment: The best thing to know is to have few dry runs (small scale), always think about balancing the cost & performance of the application. And to guide you further there a lot of reference that AWS provides for common use-case such as for ML. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/machine-learning-for-telecommunication/architecture.html